# insert in to table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, common-table-expression

i have that syntax

```
WITH sql_query AS (
.....
)
select id from sql_query;
```

i want to insert the "id" into another table like this

```
i have that syntax

WITH sql_query AS (
.....
) insert into temp_table
select id from sql_query;
```

but this doesnt work - any idea how to insert the selected data into table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is the other way around, like `insert ... with ... select ...`:

```
insert into temp_table (id)
with sql_query AS (.....) 
select id from sql_query;
```

Note that I added the list of columns to the `insert` clause (I assumed that the target column is called `id`). This is a good practice in SQL, that I would recommend adopting.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, the `with` goes with the `select`.  So try:

```
insert into temp_table
    with sql_query as (
    .....
    )
    select id
    from sql_query;
```

I would also suggest that you list the columns in the insert, so:

```
insert into temp_table (id)
. . .
```

This is just a good practice to always follow to avoid errors.